# Sufficient condition for a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ to have a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I know that if $f: [a,b] \to [a,b]$ is continuous then by the intermediate value theorem it must have a fixed point. However, I recently saw this theorem stating that given a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $, if there is some $M >0$ such that $x \in B(0,M): d_2(x,f(x)) < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Then $f$ has a fixed point.

Intuitively I would say that the fixed point is $x$. But I wouldn't know how to actually show that $f(x) - x = 0$. Any hints?

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping)?  This may be a predecessor.  You may not have stated it properly.  I believe it should be for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is an $x$ so that $d_2(x,f(x)) \lt \epsilon$.  Note that you may not get the same $x$ for every $\epsilon$ so you cannot just take $x$.  You should take the limit of the $x$'s as $\epsilon \to 0$

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, the $x$ might be different for every $\epsilon$. I know that contractive functions are Lipschitz where the constant is less than one and there is a result that states that contractive functions have at most one fixed point. However it is not clear to me why this particular $f$ is contractive.

Comment: By hypothesis $x \to f(x)$, but does this allow me to conclude that $x$ is a fixed point? I don't know how to use the fact that $|x| < M$. @RossMillikan

Comment: I don't think that $|x| \lt M$ matters.  There is nothing special about the origin here, so $x$ could be very far from the origin.  Imagine taking a series of $\epsilon$s that converge to $0$, like $.1, .01, .001, \ldots$ and getting an $x$ for each one.  You want to prove that these $x$s converge to some point $y$ and that $f(y)=y$.

Comment: @RossMillikan The fact that you can choose the $x$'s from a bounded region does matter. Consider the function $f:\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R} $ given by $f(x)=x+e^{-x^2}$ This clearly has no fixed point and yet for any $\epsilon$ we can find $x$ s.t. $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $x$. The origin isn't important, but boundedness is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's prove the following :

*Let $X$ is a compact metric space, and $f : X \rightarrow X$ a continuous function such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $d(x,f(x)) < \varepsilon$. Then $f$ has a fixed point.*

**Proof :** Let $F : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x)=d(x,f(x))$.

$F$ is continuous over the compact set $X$, therefore, $F(X)$ is compact.

But by assumption on $f$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, there exists $x_n \in X$ such that $F(x_n) < \dfrac{1}{n}$.

The sequence $F(x_n)$ therefore converges to $0$, and since $F(X)$ is closed, then $0 \in F(X)$.

This means exactly that there exists $x \in X$ such that $F(x)=0$, i.e. such that $\boxed{f(x)=x}$.

Comment: In our case, by this reasoning we can say that the fixed point is in $[-M,M]$, right?

Comment: Yes, if the hypothesis is "$\exists M > 0, \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists x \in B(0,M), d(x,f(x)) < \varepsilon$", then you can just replace $X$ by $B(0,M)$ in my answer to get that the fixed point belongs to $B(0,M)$.

Answer (score 2):

This criteria works only for compact domain and does not necessarily work unbounded domains. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, we have,
Let $\epsilon_n = \epsilon/2^n$.
Let $M$ be such that we can find $x_n$ such that $|x_n| \leq M$ and $|x_n-f(x_n)| < \epsilon_n$. Now $x_n$ is an infinite sequence in compact set hence has a subsequence which converges. Let $x^*$ be the limit of the subsequence $x_{n_k}$ mentioned above.

Then $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |x_{n_k} - f(x_{n_k})|  = 0$.
But since $x_{n_k} \rightarrow x^*$, we have $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |x_{n_k} - f(x_{n_k})|  = |x^* - f(x^*)|$.

Hence $|x^* - f(x^*)| = 0$ and hence $x^*$ is the fixed point.

The proof is general and works even for continuous functions over compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What we know is that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and that there is some $M> 0$ such that for every $\epsilon> 0, |x| < M \Rightarrow |x-f(x)| < \epsilon$.
I didn't really understand how you built the sequence $M_n$ starting from these hypothesis.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear. The actual condition is there exists an $M$ such that, for every $\epsilon>0$,  there exists an $x$ such that $|x| \leq M$ and $d(x,f(x)) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Hope the edited answer is clear now.